# Using Fast Fourier transform in Python

Tags: matlab, python, programming, fast-fourier-transform

I have a problem with using the FFT command in Python. The output of the FFT command in Matlab is different from its' output in Scipy/Numpy packages. I want to use the Matlab engine for Python. However, it seems that it is not possible to send complex data (as an FFT input argument)to Matlab. I wondered if someone has a similar problem and how to solve it?

Any help from you is appreciated.

Comment: There are various slightly conventions about how the discrete Fourier transform is defined. The various definitions disagree only superficially. Probably Matlab and Python are using slightly different conventions. The documentation might clarify this. You might be able to multiply by a constant to make the results agree.

Comment: Give an example of how the results are different.